# Copy properties to modules in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I need to put my own properties (many different) to many modules. The properties contain sensitive data (DB passwords for example), so I cannot put it to my git repository. For now, I have 2 Jenkins jobs:

- **First** clones my "project" and builds it.
- **The second** clones my other repository that contains only properties and some .sh files. Then I copy properties from the second project and paste it into my .jar file.
  The problem is that I have to "unzip" (or "unjar"?) the jar file, then paste properties, and after that "jar" the file again. Not so clear.

Good thing about that is if I want to change my properties I don't have to rebuild all project. Just run the second job and that is all.
I found some other options:

## Jasypt

So I can encrypt my properties. Then I can store it in my repository. Not bad, but I do not see what password is stored. Next question - when I want to change something in my properties I need to build all over again. So Jasypt is a good idea to make your sensitive data safer but did not resolve my problem.

## maven-remote-resources-plugin

I don`t know it at all, but maybe it is a better way to paste my properties into my project?

Maybe There are other ways to do that? Or maybe now I am doing it how it should looks? Btw. I am using spring boot 2.0.3.

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Comment: Oh, WOW! I think it fits my problem. Thank you :)